# Push notification architecture with rest or web services

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, push

We currently have a solution, using web services (implement via WCF) where client software periodically call a service to retrieve a list of new items waiting for them, then for each item, calls a separate service to do the actual download.  This is the typical message polling scenario, and is relatively simple in implementation and trouble free.  It does not give a near real time messaging solution however.   For real time messaging you'd want more of a push notification architecture.

Because of security concerns we do not want clients to expose interfaces that our system can call because then each client needs to secure that exposed interface among other concerns.

Id like to explore the option of the client still initiating the connection to the server as we do today, but instead of polling, we maintain the connection and once the client has completed the connection, the server is now able to push messages to the client.

Our clients base may be implementing their solution on a variety of platforms, from Linux to Windows, .Net to PHP, etc.  Additionally, clients vendors have a varying degree of technical capabilities so complexity of the solution is a factor here.  Can SOAP or REST services be used in this type of architecture? Are there other technologies I should be looking at?  Our server side part of the solution would need to be a .net one.

Comment: From your description sounds like you need web sockets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186723/Push-Messages-in-RESTful-WCF-Web-Application-with

Comment: Microsoft created SignalR (which uses web sockets by default) to handle the exact set of requirements that you describe. Recommend looking into SignalR, and I think you'll see that it fits the bill.

Comment: @SlimsGhost - The client may not be a browser, it might be a windows application, or something running on Linux.   Can SignalR fit this scenario?

Comment: Note that because your clients will run on a variety of platforms, they _might_ have a problem working with signalR enpoint. For example - their language might not have a ready-made library to work with SignlarR and they might become upset because of this. Pure web sockets is more widespread strandard and every sane language has a client for it.